# Given an integer $n>0$, $\forall 0<k\le n$, the total factor $2$ does the sequence contain?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For example,

if $n=2$, we have a sequence: $1,2$, where $2$ has one factor $2$, so the counting function: $\phi(2)=1$

if $n=4$, we have a sequence: $1,2,3,4$, where $4=2\cdot2$ has two factor $2$, so the counting function: $\phi(4)=\phi(2)+2=3$

if $n=6$, we have a sequence: $1,2,3,4,5,6$, where $6=2\cdot 3$ has one factor $2$, so the counting function: $\phi(6)=\phi(4)+1=4$

if $n=8$, we have a sequence: $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$, where $8=2\cdot 2\cdot2$ has three factor $2$, so the counting function: $\phi(8)=\phi(6)+3=7$

Is there a name for this counting function and what is the general formula?

Comment: This is not clear.  Are you trying to define a function on the even integers?  If so, is your (recursive) definition just $F(2)=1$ and $F(2n)=F(2n-2)+v_2(2n)$ where, as usual, $v_2(k)$ is the order to which $2$ divides $k$?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. On odd integers, this function is trivially equal to the value on the prior even integer. @lulu

Comment: So, then, I believe you are  counting  $2n$ minus the number of $1's$ in the binary expansion of $2n$, as in [A005187](https://oeis.org/A005187).